# How much incoming traffic can I process on a network card with two 100GbE ports?

Tags: networking

How much incoming traffic can I process on a network card with two 100GbE ports? Is it 100Gbs or 200Gbs incoming traffic? I'm talking about the Mellanox MCX516A-CCAT ConnectX-5 EN for example, which have two 100gbE ports.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [spec sheet](https://www.mellanox.com/related-docs/prod_adapter_cards/PB_ConnectX-5_EN_Card.pdf) this particular card is capable of Link Aggregation and use of both connectors at 100Gbps each at full duplex simultaneously. However, the recommended PCIe 3.0 x16 slot on your motherboard has a bandwidth max of 126Gbps. **No, it is not capable of 200Gbps throughput directly onto your machine.** It is however capable of communicating to two clients separately at 100Gbps each (as a sort of network switch).

If you were to upgrade to the MCX516A-CDAT which supports PCIe 4.0 x16 that supports up to 252.08Gbps on the PCIe bus, than it is theoretically possible. Of course, you would need a motherboard, and CPU that would supports that new tech. As well as the necessary OS, Drivers, and preferably a known good network Switch that supports Link-Aggregation to achieve those speeds. Not mention something on your network to talk to.

If you were able to get all the necessary upgrades and equipment, in theory you could successfully use Link Aggregation to achieve the 2x100gbps speed (Mellanox refers to their method of Link Aggregation as RoCE-LAG) However, while it does appear to be supported on the [latest Firmware version](https://www.mellanox.com/pdf/firmware/ConnectX5-FW-16_23_1020-release_notes.pdf) it may require some [specific steps](https://community.mellanox.com/s/article/How-to-Configure-RoCE-over-LAG-ConnectX-4-ConnectX-5) to get it work as its disabled by default.

So now that you have the data on your motherboard, what are you going to do with it? The NVMe SSD speeds don't even come anywhere close to that. You would need to setup some kind of RAID or RAM disk array so crazy I'm not even going to calculate it.

At over $1,000 just for a NIC this product is obviously intended for ultra high end data servers. What exactly are you intending to do with all that bandwidth?

Comment: This is a decent answer to a very low quality question. +1